# AngularJS: infinite scroll with ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I am new in angular. so hopping many site to read nice article on angular code example. So today i visited a site http://www.dotnetawesome.com/2016/03/infinite-scroll-for-facebook-like-pagination-angularjs.html

which come with a example like how to create infinite scroll with angularJS.

Here i will post some question which is not clear to me. So please answer and guide about those syntax and code in the article because i need to understand.

1) There is one function called `NextPage()` which the function name has been assign with directive name like this way `<div infinityscroll="NextPage()" style="height:400px; overflow:auto;">` ?

```
$scope.NextPage = function () {
    if ($scope.CurrentPage < $scope.TotalPage) {
        $scope.CurrentPage += 1;
        GetEmployeeData($scope.CurrentPage);
    }
}
```

Tell me what does it mean to assign function name with directive name

`<div infinityscroll="NextPage()" style="height:400px; overflow:auto;">` ?

Does it mean when directive will load then the NextPage() function will be called or it has different meaning ?

2) See the directive code first

```
app.directive('infinityscroll', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            element.bind('scroll', function () {
                if ((element[0].scrollTop + element[0].offsetHeight) == element[0].scrollHeight) {
                    //scroll reach to end
                    scope.$apply(attrs.infinityscroll)
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

What is the meaning of this line `scope.$apply(attrs.infinityscroll)`

Hence i am new so i am fumbling when reading article on angular js v1+. so please answer my 2 questions in details to guide me. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NextPage()` is the expression that is evaluated when the Infinite scroll plugin detects that the user has scrolled to the end of the page, or the end of the directive.

`scope.$apply(attr.infinityscroll)` is telling Angular to run a digest loop after evaluating the expression.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$apply

Comment: sorry this is not clear scope.$apply(attr.infinityscroll) is telling Angular to run a digest loop after the expression has run. can give me more knowledge about this line scope.$apply(attr.infinityscroll)